# 'gcloud deploy' complains about having both a .gcloudignore and skip_files even though I have neither

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-app-engine-python

I'm trying to deploy a Django (v2.1) app to App Engines Python37 runtime. This is my `app.yaml` which was taken from a [Google example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/standard/django/app.yaml):

```
# [START django_app]
runtime: python37
#api_version: 1
#threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static/
- url: .*
  script: <project_name>.wsgi.application

# Only pure Python libraries can be vendored
# Python libraries that use C extensions can
# only be included if they are part of the App Engine SDK 
# Using Third Party Libraries: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27
#libraries:
#- name: MySQLdb
#  version: 1.2.5
# [END django_app]

# Google App Engine limits application deployments to 10,000 uploaded files per
# version. The skip_files section allows us to skip virtual environment files
# to meet this requirement. The first 5 are the default regular expressions to
# skip, while the last one is for all env/ files.
#skip_files:
#- ^(.*/)?#.*#$
#- ^(.*/)?.*~$
#- ^(.*/)?.*\.py[co]$
#- ^(.*/)?.*/RCS/.*$
#- ^(.*/)?\..*$
#- ^env/.*$
```

All but the most basic settings are commented out and there is no `.gcloudignore` file in the repo. Yet when doing `gcloud app deploy` I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) You cannot use skip_files and have a .gcloudignore file in the same application. You should convert your skip_files patterns and put them in your .gcloudignore file. For information on the format and syntax of .gcloudignore files, see https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore.
```

I've read somewhere that a .glcoudignore is created automatically during deployment, but even that shouldn't be a problem since I have no `skip_files` in my `app.yaml`.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gcloud deploy is seeing the `#skip_files:` line, even though you have it commented out.  Delete that line, or change its spelling.

Comment: Hm, that's really strange: I had tried removing these lines and it changed nothing, deleting all comment lines however did make it work. I don't know why it can't handle the comments, but thanks for your help!

Comment: They still haven't fixed this, apparently. Came across the same problem just now.